# sorting elements in Linked list

Tags: c

I wanted to sort the elements in linked list in ascending order.
I have written the following code:

```
void don(struct node *head)
{
struct node *god,*tmp=head,*current,*bak;
for(god=head;god->next!=NULL;god=god->next)
{
    current=god->next;
    for(bak->next=tmp;(bak->next)!=(god->next);bak=bak->next)
    {
        if((current->data)<(bak->next->data))
        {
            god->next=current->next;
            current->next=god;
            bak->next=current;
        }
    }
}
}
```

But its resulting into infinte loop.

Please help in correcting the code :) !

I want it to do it in this way

```
5-2-3-1-4
2-5-3-1-4
2-3-5-1-4
1-2-3-5-4
1-2-3-4-5
```

Comment: This sort of looks like bubble sort, but can you clarify which algorithm you want to use?

Comment: @timBiegeleisen its insertion sort

Comment: `for(bak->next=tmp;` - and you set `bak` *where* exactly ? Your code is dereferencing an indeterminate pointer and invoking *undefined behavior*. I stopped reading at that, so there's bound to be more.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
 god->next=current->next;
```

breaks the first **for()** loop:

```
 for(god=head;god->next!=NULL;god=god->next)
```

Comment: Please explain,not able to understand

Comment: The loop expects that it always goes forward. Unfortunately, it may go back by changing god->next  inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void don(struct node *head)
{
struct node *god,*tmp=head,*current,*bak;
int data;
for(god=head;god->next!='\0';god=god->next)
{
    current=god->next;
    for(current;current->next!='\0';current=current->next)
    {
        if((current->data)<(god->data))
        {
            data=current->data;
            current->data=god->data;
            god->data=data;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how to do it with insertion sort?

Comment: i will check and let you know

Comment: what is your node contain (previous,data,next) or (data,next)

Comment: contains data,next

Comment: then in insertion we have to check from current to 0 or first postion then how can we go back without prev?

Comment: thats why i used bak

Comment: in insertion sort we are going from current position to first means traverse whole list up to first in your code we can not traverse for that you have to use doubly linked list (prev,data,next)

Comment: so try to use above code for sorting it is work fine for sorting